Need VBA code and syntax to automate Conditional Formatting across multiple columns
My goal is to find the UNIQUE MINIMUM value in each COLUMN having a Range D2:D13, E2:E13..... to V2:V13, with the EXCEPTION of Colum M. (This is 19 columns, skipping the 10th column).  Each cell in the Range D2:V13 is light blue formatted, and I want to highlight the UNIQUE MINIMUM for each COLUMN....if there is a UNIQUE MINIMUM.  Each cell with a UNIQUE MINIMUM will be WHITE an all others in that column will remain the light blue.  All help would be much appreciated.
Sample of spreadsheet (Note, I've only added conditional formatting to Columns D, E, and F)

I've successfully used this code for a single column, but would like to automate it across all 13 columns. I have 6 different tables, with various number of rows from 50 to 100 rows in each table.  I believe the Range...Select and the FormatConditions.Add statements have to have the column reference changed for each column and that everything after is common. Below would be the code for Column D only.
Range("D2:D13").Select   
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _   
    "=AND($D2=MIN($D$2:$D$13),COUNTIF($D$2:$D$13),$D2)=1)"   
' Below is the same for all columns   
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority   
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font   
    .Bold=True   
    .Italic=False   
    .TintAndShade=0   
End With   
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior   
    .PatternColarIndex=xlAutomatic   
    .Color=vbWhite   
    .TintAndShade=0   
End With   
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue=False   


Your countif doesn't look right? Should that be =AND($D2=MIN($D$2:$D$13),COUNTIF($D$2:$D$13,$D2)=1)

--blue cells
semicolon separator
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A$2:A$6;MIN(A$2:A$6))=1;A2=MIN(A$2:A$6));FALSE;TRUE)

coma separator
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A$2:A$6,MIN(A$2:A$6))=1,A2=MIN(A$2:A$6)),FALSE,TRUE)

--white cells
semicolon separator
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A$2:A$6;MIN(A$2:A$6))=1;A2=MIN(A$2:A$6));TRUE;FALSE)

coma separator
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A$2:A$6,MIN(A$2:A$6))=1,A2=MIN(A$2:A$6)),TRUE,FALSE)




W_O_L_F - Thank you for a quick reply. I would have responded sooner except our refrigerator chose this moment to die and I had to find a quick replacement.

W_O_L_F - Thank you for a quick reply.   Changing the separator from a ";" to a "," allow your solution does work with my regional settings.  To clarify my need, I have 18 columns which means the FormatConditions statement would have to be changed for each column. I was thinking I could use a FOR/NEXT along with a CELLS statement to cycle through each Column and have the code change the column identifier.  But  I can't get the syntax to work with CELLS (using a variable to change the column) along with the required ABSOLUTE  parameters.  Any help with that?  Thanks in advance.

You do not need a for loop. As long at your reference the first cell in the region and be sure to use $ to lock rows and columns as apporopriare , Excel handles that for you. I have updated the example. When recreating this I noticed I got some weird characters when copying the code. Paste it to notpad and copy from there solved it for me.

W_O_L_F  -  your solution absolutely worked. There is only one other minor problem I need to address.  Even though my original example showed I was only looking to solve the Unique/Minimum for cells that had data in them, I will have rows within the range that are completely blank and also have a value of "0".  Blank and "0" need to be differentiated.  Only columns having a "0" as a unique minimum, ALSO highlight (with white) as if it were also a unique minimum.  I'm going to try and add additional criteria to handle that situation, but if you have any ideas I'd be happy to see them. Thanks !!
